# I need to control in open and close of SliderDrawer

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I need to control in open and close of SliderDrawer IN FLUTTER WEB APPLICATION

Iam trying to control in open and close of SliderDrawer IN FLUTTER WEB APPLICATION if ypu can help me in this leave your answer here Slider viewer

Comment: `Scaffold.of(context).closeDrawer()` and `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`?

Comment: it open when tab in side of screen automatic How do I prevent that?